# I can not determine if it is a prime number

Tags: c

The below program correctly outputs the divisors of the input numbers, but it does not correctly report whether the inputs are prime. For example, when the input is 13, it does not print "The number you entered is a prime number."  What's wrong with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
   int num;
   bool isPrime = true;

   printf("Enter a number: ");
   while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
   {
      for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; ++i)  
      {
         if (num % i == 0)
         {
            if (i * i != num)
            {
               printf("%d ve %d, divides %d\n", i, num / i, num);
            }
            else
            {
               printf("%d divides %d.\n", i, num);
            }

            isPrime = false;
         }
      }
   }

   if (isPrime)
   {
      printf("The number you entered is a prime number.");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can find (all) the divisors of a number, then you know whether it is prime.  Prime numbers are those that have no divisors other than 1 and themselves.

Comment: It *is* a C question. Reset `isPrime` to `true` in the beginning of *each* `while` iteration.

Comment: 'isPrime = false' is never reached.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi Why?

Comment: Works if you put 13 as first number at least on my VS 2010 compiler, however if one of the numbers isn't prime then it doesn't work (which might be intended)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `if` -> `else` -> `isPrime= false` The `else`  is a catch-all here

Comment: I don't know why the first bunch of comments. The primality test algorithm is correct. The restarting of it is not.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi So? It is outside of the if/else block and will happen in any case.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yepp, now I see it too, will accept it and go back to bed ;-)

Comment: @Bharadwaj can you please tell me what am I missing. Sure I am in a blind mind situation now.

Comment: @EugeneSh., that would be because the title and original text of the question could be interpreted as an "I don't know how" instead of "my program is broken".

Comment: @Lyrk Did you read my comments? How you are in blind situation if I pointed you the solution?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do you mean "  isPrime = false;" is never reached?

Comment: No. Read my very first comment. What is never reached is the printing the result of primality test.

Comment: @Lyrk I have answered Hope it helps !

Comment: @Lyrk Did the answer help you if yes Please give that a correct answer symbol !

Comment: Set `IsPrime` in the `else` statement (i.e. if printing a divisor, THAT is when `isPrime` should be set to `false`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have missed 2 things  !

1. You should have printed inside the while loop !
2. In addition to that you didn't change the status of `isPrime=true;` !

Hope this answers your question !

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    int main(void)
    {
    int num;
    bool isPrime = true;
    while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; ++i)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                if (i * i != num)
                {
                    printf("%d ve %d, divides %d\n", i, num / i, num);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%d divides %d.\n", i, num);
                }

                isPrime = false;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime)
        {
            printf("The number you entered is a prime number.\n");
        }
        isPrime=true;
    }



    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is not solving the problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well, part of it. ;) The output should be in the loop as well.

Comment: How is it not solving the problem !

Comment: You missed Eugene's comment above. `isPrime` is never reset after it is set to `false` once.

Comment: Try it. With input 13 and 22.

Comment: Or even better, try it with 22 and 13.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah, I meant that :)

Comment: Now check with it ! Did you check it !

Comment: Thank you. Now it is correct. Now add some wording with explanation and get some upvotes

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote for my answer ! Just to improve !

Comment: Downvotes are probably because the answer was incorrect initially. Lack of explanation might contribute as well.

Comment: Including a copy of your screen is not conducive to upvoting either.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is that scanf is in a while loop if there's a valid input but you are checking & printing if it's prime outside of the loop... if you expect this program just get one input and validate it once, then you just need to change that `while` to `if`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
   int num;
   bool isPrime = true;

   printf("Enter a number: ");
   if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
   {
      for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; ++i)  
      {
         if (num % i == 0)
         {
            if (i * i != num)
            {
               printf("%d ve %d, divides %d\n", i, num / i, num);
            }
            else
            {
               printf("%d divides %d.\n", i, num);
            }

            isPrime = false;
         }
      }
   }

   if (isPrime)
   {
      printf("The number you entered is a prime number.");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If you expect this program goes in a loop to keep on getting input and validating if it's prime or not, this should do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
   int num;
   bool isPrime = true;

   while (1)
   { 
       isPrime=true;
       printf("Enter a number: ");
       if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
       {
          for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; ++i)  
          {
             if (num % i == 0)
             {
                if (i * i != num)
                {
                   printf("%d ve %d, divides %d\n", i, num / i, num);
                } 
               else
               {
                   printf("%d divides %d.\n", i, num);
               }

                isPrime = false;
             }
          }
       }

       if (isPrime)
       {
          printf("The number you entered is a prime number.\n");
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you entered a prime number, your while loop doesn't break. Try it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(void) {
int num;
bool isPrime = true, finishIt = false;

printf("Enter a number: ");
while (1) {
    while (1) {
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
            continue;

        if (num == 0) {
            finishIt = true;
            break;
        }


        int i;
        for (i = 2; i * i <= num; ++i) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                if (i * i != num) {
                    printf("%d ve %d, divides %d\n", i, num / i, num);
                } else {
                    printf("%d divides %d.\n", i, num);
                }

                isPrime = false;
            }
        }

        if (i * i >= num)
            break;
    }

    if (isPrime) {
        printf("The number you entered is a prime number.");
    }

    isPrime = true;

    if (finishIt)
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another incorrect answer. Will work for first input only

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've just changed it.